# Is &*NULL well-defined in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, null-pointer

In what version(s) of the C++ standards (if any) is the following well-defined?

```
void foo(void) {
    char *nullPtr = NULL;
    &*nullPtr;
}
```

Note that I am specifically asking about `&*nullPtr` here. I am aware that simply `*nullPtr` is undefined - but this is a separate question and hence the currently-linked "duplicate" is not a duplicate.

Note that I am not assigning the result to anything - the second line is a simple statement.

This *should* be a question with an obvious answer, but (as seemingly happens way too often on such questions) I have heard just as many people say the answer is "obviously undefined" as "obviously defined".

On a rather related note, what about the following? Should `foo` produce a read of c?

```
extern volatile char c;

void bar(void) {
    volatile char *nonnullptr = &c;
    &*nonnullptr;
}
```

(C version of the same question: [Is &*NULL well-defined in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691357/is-null-well-defined-in-c))

Comment: Pick a language. Language-lawyer and C/C++ don't go usually go together since C and C++ are completely different languages. That said, in C dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior, but [`&*E` is equivalent to `E` even for null pointers.](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note102)

Comment: I wish to know in both. Are you saying it would be better to create two separate questions?

Comment: To me it seems like this would be best, since this question is about language-lawyer nitpicking of two distinct languages (others may disagree). Yet I am not sure if the two languages are in agreement on this issue or not; they may be.

Comment: @DavidBowling - I have done so; thank you. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691357/is-null-well-defined-in-c).

Comment: @Ben-Voigt - the linked question addresses \*NULL, whereas I am asking about &*NULL. These are two separate issues. (Note that in C, for instance, the former is undefined whereas the latter is defined.). As such the linked question does *not* answer my question.

Comment: @AJNeufeld - the linked question addresses \*NULL, whereas I am asking about &*NULL. These are two separate issues. (Note that in C, for instance, the former is undefined whereas the latter is defined.). As such the linked question does *not* answer my question. (My kingdom for a multinotify.)

Comment: @TLW: The third line of code in the linked question is `int* q = &*p;   // undefined?` which completely covers your case.  Please spend a little more time when someone offers you an existing answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - /question/answer/, sorry. The answers do not address the case at all - they all focused in on *nullPtr even though, as I've said, in C at least the two cases are rather different.

Comment: @TLW: You should probably read this as well as it contradicts the assumptions in your question: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is four questions in one.

---

`&*nullPtr` is well-defined in C since C99, which says of the unary `&` operator:

> If the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that
>   operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if both
>   were omitted, [...]

See WG14 [N721](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n721.htm) and [DR076](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_076.html).

---

`&*nullPtr` is formally undefined in all revisions of C++ (by omission: unary `&` is specified to produce a pointer to "the designated object", and unary `*` is specified to produce "an lvalue referring to the object [...] to which the expression points"; a null pointer value points to no object), although the direction of [core issue 232](https://wg21.link/cwg232) is to make this well-defined.

---

`&*nonnullptr` produces no volatile read of `*nonnullptr`. Unary `&` expects an lvalue operand; no lvalue conversion (for C) or lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (for C++) is performed for `*nonnullptr`.

Comment: At the suggestion of @DavidBowling I have split this into C and C++ questions.

Comment: This is... amusing. So in other words in C++ it _is_ a dereference for purposes of UB, but _isn't_ for purposes of volatiles? Yay consistency.

Comment: Core Issue 232 proposed null references and has had no updates for 13 years ... it seems that it's directly is currently "going nowhere"

Comment: @M.M My understanding is that CWG simply had too many other higher-priority items.

Comment: @TLW "So in other words in C++ it is a dereference for purposes of UB, but isn't for purposes of volatiles? Yay consistency." - Why would you expect consistency between C and C++? They are (at this point in time) *entirely different* languages that just happen to share a (diminishing) common subset of valid code. Don't treat C as a subset of C++ - it isn't (any more, and has not been for many years). Ok. I probably misunderstood that comment as referring to C vs C++ where it was actually about dereferencing versus volatile. Whoops, sorry.

Comment: Please reread the comment. That comment has nothing to do with C. Read it as "So in other words in C++ it is a dereference for purposes of UB, but [in C++ it] isn't for purposes of volatiles? Yay consistency."